# Quickly append value to a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

PHP has a really quick way to append a value to an array:

```
$array[] = 'value';
```

What is the easiest way to do this in python without needing an index number?
 Also, is there an easy way to do this with a list nested inside a dictionary, like this PHP equivalent..

```
$array['associative'][] = 'value';
```

Comment: -0.  This has a very low google difficulty level.  This is covered official python tutorial (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/). Appending to a list is shown in section 3.1.4 and mentioned again in section 5.1.

Comment: This has very low tab completion difficulty ;).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my_list.append(value)
```

or

```
my_dict[key].append(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way for dict of lists is:

```
my_dict.setdefault(key,list()).append(value)
```

that is equivalent for

```
if not key in my_dict:
    my_dict[key] = list()
nested_list = my_dict[key]
nested_list.append(value)
```

Thist is safe when my_dict doesnt have any list at key.

In earlier proposed variant:

```
my_dict[key].append(value)
```

which is equivalent for

```
nested_list = my_dict[key]
nested_list.append(value)
```

`KeyError` will be raised if my_dict has no item at key

But if my_dict[key] has no 'append' method `AttributeError` would be raised in both variants

**UPD (important!):** in construction like `my_dict.setdefault(key,list())` a `list` instance is created even if `my_dict` has `key`!

Answer (score 1):

How about the `append()` list method? e.g.,

```
 myList.append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist.append(value)
```

See "pydoc list".