# for loops and list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I've been far from python for a while. when I try bellow code it gives me **Index Error**

```
n = int(input())
array = []
for i in range(n):
    array[i] = i+1
```

Comment: Are you trying to append values to the array? (P.S.: It's actually a list, not an array)

Comment: try `array.append(i+1)`

Comment: It's a list, you add value to the list with the append method. If you call array[i], the element i must exist in the list, else you get an Index Error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quickly append value to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215292/quickly-append-value-to-a-list)

Comment: [How to create a list of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558007/how-can-i-generate-a-list-of-consecutive-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an obvious mistake because I'm learning C right know. in C you can do it in this way:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    array [i] = i+1
}
```

but in python you must put your element you want to insert inside a bracket:

```
for i in range(n):
    array += [i+1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use append method:

```
n = int(input())
array = []
for i in range(n):
    array.append(i+1)
```

Your error appears because you are calling `array[0]` which doesn't exist and trying to assign value to it.

Comment: [Please don't answer obvious duplicates.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to create a *list*, then you should **append** elements to your list:

```
myList = list()
list.append(element)
```

You can also create a *dictionary* where you can **index** elements:

```
myDict = dict()
mydict[i] = element
```